# ffmpeg extract audio corresponding to a certain number of frames

Tags: ffmpeg

We know that:
`ffmpeg -ss 10 -t 30 -i file.mp3 file.wav`
extracts 30 sec of audio starting from 10th second

How can we extract a portion of audio whose duration is expressed as number of frames rather than in seconds?
For instance, how do I extract the portion of audio corresponding to 120 frames starting from the 10th second?

Comment: I expect that this is possible with `-frames[:stream_specifier] framecount (output,per-stream) Stop writing to the stream after framecount frames.`, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Eike, I did not manage to make it work. What would be the full command?